# Trying to parse XML with multiple items in subchild using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which im trying to parse with PHP and then insert it into a database.

This is a sample of the XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
    <category name="Parent Cat">
        <sub-category name="Child Cat">
            <item id="2828" code="AC123">
                <productId>2828</productId>
                <productCode>AC123</productCode>
                <live>1</live>
                <productTitle>Product Title</productTitle>
                <description><![CDATA[<p>*****</p>]]></description>
                    <imageLink>http://www.***.co.uk/uploads/images/products/product_2828.jpg</imageLink>
                <price>99.99</price>
                <rrp>99.99</rrp>
                <brandName>Brand</brandName>
                <stock>100</stock>
            </item>
        <item id="2829" code="AC234">
            <productId>2829</productId>
            <productCode>AC234</productCode>
            <live>1</live>
            <productTitle>Product Title</productTitle>
            <description><![CDATA[<p>*****</p>]]></description>
            <imageLink>http://www.***.co.uk/uploads/images/products/product_2829.jpg</imageLink>
            <price>99.99</price>
            <rrp>99.99</rrp>
            <brandName>Brand</brandName>
            <stock>100</stock>
        </item>
```

This the PHP code I have so far which is successfully parsing the item's until the end of the sub category group.

```
$feed =  simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

$counter = 0;
foreach ($feed->category->{'sub-category'}->item as $product) {

$sku = "A1 - " . mysql_real_escape_string($product->productCode);  
$products_id = mysql_real_escape_string($product->productId);              
$products_code = mysql_real_escape_string($product->productCode);
$live = mysql_real_escape_string($product->live);
$product_title = mysql_real_escape_string($product->productTitle);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($product->description);
$image_link = mysql_real_escape_string($product->imageLink);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($product->price);
$rrp = mysql_real_escape_string($product->rrp);
$brand_name = mysql_real_escape_string($product->brandName);
$stock = mysql_real_escape_string($product->stock);

$counter++;
}
```

I need the code to process all item and also record the Category and sub category associated with each item. All together there are 8 main categories, 113 sub categories and 1901 items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Innov8, what's the specific question?

Comment: @michi 'I need the code to process all item and also record the Category and sub category associated with each item.'

Comment: "I need the code" is not SO's purpose. Rather ask a specific **How**-question, show what you have tried and where you got stuck. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking